# React functional/stateless pure component

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginning to switch to functional/stateless components in React, like the one below.

I do however have a problem with react-chartjs-2 re-drawing my charts, even though the data for them didn't change. Before I switched to functional components, this was easily solved by using Reacts PureComponent.

Is there a way to make React use the PureComponent for a stateless function?

```
const ListGroup = props => {
  const {title, width} = (props);

  return (
    <ul className={"grid"} style={{width}}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      {props.children}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: How would using React's PureComponent allow the re-render without a data change? Were you forcing it somehow with one of the lifecycle methods? Additionally, why would you _want_ this behaviour?

Comment: It's the exact opposite. I don't want it to re-render components, when the props haven't changed. PureComponents solves this issue that react-chartjs-2 is causing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since React v16.6.0 you can use [`React.memo()`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#reactmemo):

```
import React from 'react';

const PureListGroup = React.memo(ListGroup);
```

With React versions before v16.6.0, You can use [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) (discontinued but still maintained) and wrap the component with the [`pure`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#pure) or [`onlyUpdateForKeys`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#onlyupdateforkeys) higher order components:

```
import pure from 'recompose/pure';

const PureListGroup = pure(ListGroup);
```

Comment: Just a 2019 update. You no longer need to use external libraries for this. Since react 16.6 `React.memo` provides a high order component for exactly that: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html